# Creating a Voice Recognition Game with AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, speech-recognition

I have been surfing the Internet searching for a solution for offline speech recognition in Air for android and ios and have just come across this code.
I'm wondering how can I modify this code to create an application that is actually a 'Voice Recognition Game'.

I should Define/add a "sentence" to each frame and check if users voice input matches that "sentence" or not...

For example we add this sentence to frame 10 : "This is a hello world test." if timeline reaches frame 10 then :

1) Speech recognition automatically starts.

2) User's voice convert to text.

3) If user's input matches "This is a hello world test." then we continue to frame 11

4) if user's input does not match, then speech recognition starts again (To let the user his second try..his last try)

5) This time if user's input match our sentence, continue to frame 11 and if it doesn't match go to frame 1

I don't need any text to speech that is included in the code or any of controllers and I just want English as my speech to text engine.any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

here is the link to the code and source files :
https://fabricemontfort.com/voice-recognition-and-speech-synthesis-in-as3-with-air/

And here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<f:Application xmlns:f="library://ns.feathersui.com/mxml"
               xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               theme="feathers.themes.MetalWorksMobileTheme">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        import feathers.controls.Alert;

        import starling.events.Event;

        /**
         * STT and TTS AIR Native Extensions
         */

        import com.fabricemontfort.air.ezSTT;
        import com.fabricemontfort.air.ezSpeech;
        import com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages;
        import com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.STTEvent;
        import com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages;

        /**
         * Text To Speech engine
         */
        private var tts:ezSpeech = ezSpeech.instance;

        /**
         * Speech To Text engine
         */
        private var stt:ezSTT = ezSTT.instance;

        /**
         * actionButton Labels
         */
        private static const OUCH:String = "NOT SUPPORTED";
        private static const AUTH:String = "ASK PERMISSIONS";
        private static const START:String = "START LISTENING";
        private static const STOP:String = "STOP LISTENING";

        /**
         * STT/TTS utterance
         */
        private var _utterance:String = "";

        [Bindable]
        public function get utterance():String {
            return _utterance;
        }

        public function set utterance(value:String):void {
            _utterance = value;
            resultLabel.text = _utterance;
        }

        /**
         * STT Microphone volume
         */
        private var _volume:Number = 0;

        [Bindable]
        public function get volume():Number {
            return _volume;
        }

        public function set volume(value:Number):void {
            _volume = value;
        }

        /**
         * Initialize TTS speed
         */
        private var _speed:Number = 0.48;

        [Bindable]
        public function get speed():Number {
            return _speed;
        }

        public function set speed(value:Number):void {
            _speed = value;
            tts.setSpeed(speed);
        }

        /**
         * Initialize TTS pitch
         */
        private var _pitch:Number = 0.65;

        [Bindable]
        public function get pitch():Number {
            return _pitch;
        }

        public function set pitch(value:Number):void {
            _pitch = value;
            tts.setPitch(pitch);
        }

        override protected function initialize():void {
            super.initialize();

            // Hide debug messages for ezSTT and ezSpeech
            stt.debug = false;
            tts.debug = false;
            // Set TTS voice speed
            tts.setSpeed(speed);
            // Set TTS voice pitch
            tts.setPitch(pitch);
            // Set default language for engines
            stt.setLanguage(com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.EN);
            tts.setLanguage(com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.US);

            // Check if STT is supported
            if (stt.isSupported()) {
                // Check if STT is authorized
                if (stt.isAuthorized()) {
                    // Add STT listeners for final result, partial result, volume, end of speech
                    stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.PARTIAL, onSTTResult);
                    stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.FINAL, onSTTResult);
                    stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.VOL, onSTTVolume);
                    stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.STOP, onSTTStop);
                    // Everything is fine, lets start
                    actionButton.label = START;
                    // STT is not autorized
                } else {
                    // Initialize STT listener for permissions
                    stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.AUTH, onAuth);
                    actionButton.label = AUTH;
                }
                // STT is not supported
            } else {
                actionButton.label = OUCH;
                var alert:Alert = Alert.show("STT is not supported", "Error", new ListCollection(
                        [
                            {label: "OK"}
                        ]));
            }
        }

        /**
         * STT engine recognized words
         */
        private function onSTTResult(event:STTEvent):void {
            // Set utterance with partial and final result
            utterance = event.message;
        }

        /**
         * The microphone volume changed
         */
        private function onSTTVolume(event:STTEvent):void {
            // Set STT microphone volume
            volume = parseInt(event.message);
        }

        /**
         * User stopped speaking or clicked the stop button
         */
        private function onSTTStop(event:STTEvent):void {
            actionButton.label = START;
            volume = 0;
            // Wait 1 second before repeating last utterance
            setTimeout(repeatUtterance, 1000);
        }

        private function onAuth(event:STTEvent):void {
            // Check if STT is authorized
            if (stt.isAuthorized()) {
                // Remove this listener
                stt.removeEventListener(STTEvent.AUTH, onAuth);
                // Add STT listeners for final result, partial result, volume, end of speech
                stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.PARTIAL, onSTTResult);
                stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.FINAL, onSTTResult);
                stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.VOL, onSTTVolume);
                stt.addEventListener(STTEvent.STOP, onSTTStop);
                // Everything is fine, lets start
                actionButton.label = START;
                // STT is not autorized
            } else {
                // Show an error message
                var alert:Alert = Alert.show("Please give permissions and retry", "Error", new ListCollection(
                        [
                            {label: "OK"}
                        ]));
            }
        }

        private function actionButton_triggeredHandler(event:Event):void {
            // Check actionButton label
            switch (actionButton.label) {
                    // Ask for permissions
                case AUTH: {
                    stt.askUserAuthorization();
                    break;
                }
                    // Start STT engine and change label
                case START: {
                    stt.start();
                    actionButton.label = STOP;
                    break;
                }
                    // Stop STT engine and change label
                case STOP: {
                    stt.stop();
                    actionButton.label = START;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * User changed the current language
         */
        private function langPickerList_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
            // Set current language for STT and TTS engines
            stt.setLanguage(langPickerList.selectedItem.code);
            tts.setLanguage(langPickerList.selectedItem.codeSpeech);
        }

        /**
         * User asked to enforce a specific language with country code
         */
        private function forceLangTextInput_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
            // Try to enfore current language for STT and TTS engines (experimental)
            stt.forceLanguage(forceLangTextInput.text);
            tts.forceLanguage(forceLangTextInput.text);
        }

        /**
         * User asked to repeat the utterance
         */
        private function sayButton_triggeredHandler(event:starling.events.Event):void {
            repeatUtterance();
        }

        private function repeatUtterance():void {
            // if utterence is not empty
            if (utterance != "" && utterance != "[]") {
                // and tts is supported
                if (tts.isSupported()) {
                    // Let's talk
                    tts.say(utterance);
                    // tts is not supported
                } else {
                    // show a error message
                    var alert:Alert = Alert.show("TTS is not supported", "Error", new ListCollection(
                            [
                                {label: "OK"}
                            ]));
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * User changed the speed Slider
         */
        private function speedSlider_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
            speed = speedSlider.value;
        }

        /**
         * User changed the pitch Slider
         */
        private function pitchSlider_changeHandler(event:starling.events.Event):void {
            pitch = pitchSlider.value;
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- This is a vertical layout with padding and gapping of 10 -->
    <f:layout>
        <f:VerticalLayout gap="10"
                          padding="10"/>
    </f:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Fit the target component to the maximum available space -->
        <f:VerticalLayoutData id="fitScreen"
                              percentWidth="100"
                              percentHeight="100"/>

        <!-- Fit the target component to me maximum width -->
        <f:VerticalLayoutData id="fitWidth"
                              percentWidth="100"/>

        <!-- List of all supported languages -->
        <f:ListCollection id="langListCollection">
            <fx:Object label="English"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.EN}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.US}"/>
            <fx:Object label="French"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.FR}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.FR}"/>
            <fx:Object label="German"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.DE}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.DE}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Italian"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.IT}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.IT}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Spanish"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.ES}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.ES}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Chinese"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.ZH}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.ZH}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Japanese"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.JA}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.JA}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Russian"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.RU}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.RU}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Korean"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.KO}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.KO}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Portuguese"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.PT}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.PT}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Czech"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.CS}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.CS}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Dutch"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.NL}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.NL}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Polish"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.PL}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.PL}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Swedish"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.SV}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.SV}"/>
            <fx:Object label="Turkish"
                       code="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezstt.languages.TR}"
                       codeSpeech="{com.fabricemontfort.air.ezspeech.languages.TR}"/>
        </f:ListCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

    <f:Panel id="resultPanel"
             title="RESULTS"
             layoutData="{fitScreen}">
        <f:layout>
            <f:VerticalLayout padding="10"/>
        </f:layout>

        <!-- This is where user can read the utterance -->
        <f:Label id="resultLabel"
                 wordWrap="true"
                 text="{utterance}"
                 layoutData="{fitScreen}"/>

    </f:Panel>

    <f:Label text="TTS VOICE SPEED"
             layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user can change the TTS voice speed -->
    <f:Slider id="speedSlider"
              change="speedSlider_changeHandler(event)"
              layoutData="{fitWidth}"
              minimum="0"
              maximum="1"
              step="0.05"
              value="{speed}"/>

    <f:Label text="TTS VOICE PITCH"
             layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user can change the TTS voice pitch -->
    <f:Slider id="pitchSlider"
              change="pitchSlider_changeHandler(event)"
              layoutData="{fitWidth}"
              minimum="0.5"
              maximum="1.5"
              step="0.05"
              value="{pitch}"/>

    <f:Label text="STT MICROPHONE VOLUME"/>

    <!-- This is where the user can see the STT microphone volume -->
    <f:ProgressBar id="volumeBar"
                   minimum="0"
                   maximum="12"
                   value="{volume}"
                   layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user can pick a language -->
    <f:PickerList id="langPickerList"
                  change="langPickerList_changeHandler(event)"
                  focusPadding="20"
                  dataProvider="{langListCollection}"
                  layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <f:Label id="forceLangLabel"
             text="TEST A COUNTRY CODE (EXPERIMENTAL)"
             layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user can enforce a language with country code -->
    <f:TextInput id="forceLangTextInput"
                 padding="20"
                 change="forceLangTextInput_changeHandler(event)"
                 layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user have to click to give permissions, start speaking, stop speaking -->
    <f:Button id="actionButton"
              padding="20"
              triggered="actionButton_triggeredHandler(event)"
              layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

    <!-- This is where the user have to click to repeat the utterance -->
    <f:Button id="sayButton"
              padding="20"
              label="REPEAT THE LAST UTTERANCE"
              triggered="sayButton_triggeredHandler(event)"
              layoutData="{fitWidth}"/>

</f:Application>
```

Comment: Before you proceed any further, you need to stop thinking with frames and learn how to create pure AS3 programs, with no FLA sources, no timelines, no Library, just classes, architecture and external resources. As long as you are thinking with scenes, frames and timelines, the code you provided is way above your level.

Comment: I think you should tell Adobe engineers to remove scenes, frames and timeline completely out of flash...

Comment: Please don't take offense for I didn't mean any. Scenes, timelines, frames - they all are great **animation** tools, but they are to be treated as such. Then, to build a fast, responsive and graphically rich AIR app for mobile platforms, you eventually will move from classic Flash content to GPU-enabled content (powered by **Starling** in provided code), there are no scenes, timelines and frames anyway. You just won't be able to do things like you used to do for web/desktop. You will need tons of understanding too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you for your confidence on ezSTT and ezSpeech.

As indicated by Organis. The source code provided above is oriented AS3 (and Feathers MXML). It is not really thought to use the internal mechanics of Animate CC.

But nothing is lost so far. If you want to use the notions of timeline, frames, scenes, it is quite possible for you to mix both approaches.

Keep the pure AS3 base for recognition and speech synthesis, as well as for sentence checking and routing to animations.
Use the frames inside a MovieClip to show awesome anims to the player and make the connection between the two with events.

This will allow you to keep an "animation" approach while keeping the source code as simple as possible to maintain.

I hope this will help you. Happy coding with AS3.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and also your Great job ... actually I was planning to buy ezSTT and ezSpeech, but unfortunately, when I tested them I found that they only work online, Somewhere in your docs I read that if I download and install offline voices for my android it'll work offline but it didn't for me ... And Good Luck With Your Desktop Speech Recognition project ...

Comment: I'm actually checking this behavior. Please send me an email from my website. I'll give you information in a few days.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find a way to send you an email from your website...!!!

Comment: My email address is in the footer (on the right) :D

Comment: Wow,That's a first :) I was looking for @ or .com or a sign up section :D